# How to check sprite count in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have a game scene in which I created 3 stones and 3 fruits. Gamer has to throw the stone to collect fruit. I'm unable to decide approach that how to detect count of fruit and display level complete/level fail scene. Please have a look at scenarios
1.Once gamer collects all the fruits (three or n numbers of fruits). Level complete scene should get populated.
2. If gamer throws all stones but unable to collect all the fruits, level fail scene should get populated.
I'm done with creating level complete and level fail scene.
can anybody please suggest me with some example on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place stoneCounter and fruitCounter values.

```
callThrowMethod(){

if(isCollectedFruit){
fruitCounter++;

if(fruitCounter==totalFlowers)
{
// moveToLevelCompletion
}
                    }else{

stoneCounter++;

if(stoneCounter==totalStones)
{
// move ToLevelFail
}
                        }
}
```

in this way you can implement logic

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this and post my comment.